# Display output of MySQL query in one line/ horizontally

Tags: mysql

I am validating the results of a MySQL database that I created and, for that, I need some screenshots.

For example, the following query:

```
select distinct run_ID
from ngsRunStats_FK.failedRuns
where reason_fail regexp 'cannot populate readsInfo'
```

will return (output from the terminal)
[image]

But as we can see, the screenshot is quite too long.

Is there a way to, instead of display the output as a (vertical) column, to display only its **values** horizontally (e.g. like in a python list)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(run_ID ORDER BY run_ID) AS run_ID_values
FROM ngsRunStats_FK.failedRuns
WHERE reason_fail REGEXP 'cannot populate readsInfo';
```

Side note:

If you really want to match the three keywords `cannot populate readsInfo` anywhere inside a larger text within the `reason_fail` column, then consider using word boundaries with `REGEXP`:

```
WHERE reason_fail REGEXP '[[:<:]]cannot populate readsInfo[[:>:]]';
```